# Retrieve database after restarting the WP7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7-emulator

In every time I restart the Emulator,I lose the database that I created.
Is there any way to to save it so I can use it next time I use the Emulator ?
And can I access a database stored in my computer through the Emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question - No, but you *can* avoid restarting the emulator between sessions. That way the local storage will be held intact.

To your second question - No, at least not as a replacement for the internal database inside the emulator. You could probably write some custom logic to have your code query some sample data, however?

Comment: You're welcome :-) If you think my answer was correct and satisfactory, please mark it as correct, so that other people will find your question!

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) will allow you to copy your database file from the emulator to your PC and vice-versa.